# how to change string $V3FTD to other string can you show me example

Tags: javascript, php, html

how to change string $V3FTD to other string can you show me example ...i try use this str_replace but not working

Comment: Please show what string you are trying to turn it into

Comment: Which language exactly? Could you show a code example?

Comment: i want change $V3FTD to v3444ftd....language in php

Comment: `str_replace("$V3FTD", "v3444ftd", "I am a string $V3FTD ...");`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reassign the variable:

```
$string = '$V3FTD';
print $string; // $V3FTD

$string = 'v3444ftd';
print $string; // v3444ftd
```

If you want to keep hold of the original value:

```
$string = '$V3FTD';
print $string; // $V3FTD

$original = $string;

$string = 'v3444ftd';
print $string; // v3444ftd
print $original; // $V3FTD
```

If the string is part of a larger string, use str_replace:

```
$string = str_replace('$V3FTD', 'v3444ftd', 'Long string containing $V3FTD');
print $string; // Long string containing v3444ftd
```